# What is the easiest way to compile a bunch of single sheet files to a large spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

So my question is, if I have a bunch of single sheet google sheets files in a folder, what is the best way script-wise to go about copying all of those individual file sheets to a master compilation spreadsheet with a sheet within that for every one of those files copied? I am writing it manually per file right now but I'm sure there is a quicker way using loops with like [0] [1]... for the different file names, but I don't know how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function ArrayBuilder() {
    var filesource = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "X" and parents in "File_ID"');
    while(filesource.hasNext()){
        var File = filesource.next();
        var ID = File.getId();
    }
    var name = File.getName()
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID);
    var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];
    var destinationID = "File_ID";
    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID);

     sheet.copyTo(destination).setName(name); 

    var filesource = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "Y" and parents in "File_ID"');
    while(filesource.hasNext()){
        var File = filesource.next();
        var ID = File.getId();
    }
    var name = File.getName()
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID);
    var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];
    var destinationID = "File_ID";
    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID);

     sheet.copyTo(destination).setName(name); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```js
var DESTINATION_SPREADSHEET_ID = '';
var PARENT_FOLDER_ID = '';

function buildMasterSpreadsheet() {
  var destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DESTINATION_SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var searchQuery = Utilities.formatString("'%s' in parents and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'", PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
  var sourceFiles = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchQuery);

  while(sourceFiles.hasNext()){
    var file = sourceFiles.next();
    var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()).getSheets()[0];
    sourceSheet.copyTo(destinationSpreadsheet).setName(file.getName());
  }
}
```

Of course, you will have to set the variables on top to the appropriate values. This script will:

- Search files that are of type `Sheets` and that *PARENT_FOLDER_ID* are in their parents.
- For each of the files found:

  - Copy its first sheet into the destination Spreadsheet.

You can also add any other clauses you may need into the search query.

Comment: Thank you Carl for your input! I apologize I didn't mean to confuse anyone by putting the manual solution into an answer. For your script, is it possible to have a loop of that, that would change the search parameter (title contains) and the setname descriptor to the same value: i.e. (title contains "Krusty Krab")....and setname("krusty krab") but repeating with a list of constants: Krusty Krab, Chum Bucket, etc...

Comment: @WarrenMeroney No worries. I wonder, what would happen if you had two sheets called "Krusty Krab Kitchen" and "Krusty Krab Main Hall"? Since you can't have more than one sheet with the same name, how is it expected that the script react to this? Or is this situation assured to never happen? Cheers